# MySQL: Suddenly connection error without making any changes

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm running `MySQL 5.6.30 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)` on `ubuntu-16.04-x86_64` and I'm using `phpMyAdmin 4.7.7`.

Sometimes, without doing anything on the Server or phpMyAdmin, I'm getting this error message on my websites:

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

When trying to log in into phpMyAdmin I'm getting these four error messages:

> #2002 - No such file or directory – The server is not responding (or
>   the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

.

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

.

> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

.

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

After making a `reboot` everything is working fine as normal, there are no error messages any more and I'm able to login into phpMyAdmin.

Why does it happen? Any ideas?

Comment: Check your logs

Answer (score 0):

I faced that similar problem using **lamp** , check if you may have more than two MySQL path like in

Find all the other `mysql` installed in your system

```
whereis mysql

mysql: /opt/lampp/bin/mysql /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz
```

Now if in you're system two MySQL if overlapping then remove others and keep only one MySQL installed by lamp

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

Here is the link I found for apache2 i did the same with mysql and it's working
http://xmodulo.com/how-to-uninstall-and-remove-apache2-on-ubuntu-debian.html

Finally stop all the MySQL existing service running

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```